# C# Com Interop class methods are not visible in VB6?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6

I have created a C# Com Interop class in .NET and I have registered it appropriately on my dev machine as well as **set Com-Visible to true in the assembly**. However when I reference the library within my vb6 application I am able to see the library name, the class name but none of the methods or properties associated with them?

If anyone could please help me fix this problem, I have been stuck on it for quite a while!

Here is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace VNDBUtils
{
public enum VNConstants : long
{
    cenMySQLDataStore = 32
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("CF4EFB82-6EE1-4A84-9CA9-07B135888B68")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IVNSqlFormatter
{
    //Properties
    long DS_Type { get; set; }
    string DS_Query { get; set; }

    //Methods
    string Format_Entity(string strString);
    string MqStrMan_MakeStringEndWith(string strString, string strMatch);
    bool MqStrMan_StringEndsWith(string strString, string strMatch);
    string MqStrMan_MakeStringStartWith(string strString, string StrMatch);
    bool MqStrMan_StringStartsWith(string strString, string strMatch);
    string Right(string value, int length);
    string Left(string value, int maxLength);
    string Format_Value(string strString);
}



[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("3884D59D-AB76-41E7-82B6-21C66DBDCBF3")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class VNSqlFormatter : IVNSqlFormatter
{

    private const string SQUARE_LEFT = "[";
    private const string SQUARE_RIGHT = "]";

    public long DS_Type { get; set; }
    public string DS_Query { get; set; }

    public string Format_Entity(string strString)
    {           
        strString = strString.Trim();

        if (DS_Type == (long)VNConstants.cenMySQLDataStore)
        {
            return strString;
        }
        else
        {
            return MqStrMan_MakeStringEndWith(MqStrMan_MakeStringStartWith(strString, SQUARE_LEFT), SQUARE_RIGHT);
        }

    }

    public string MqStrMan_MakeStringEndWith(string strString, string strMatch)
    {
        if (MqStrMan_StringEndsWith(strString, strMatch) == false)
        {
            return strString + strMatch;
        }
        else
        {
            return strString; 
        }

    }

    public bool MqStrMan_StringEndsWith(string strString, string strMatch)
    {
        return String.Equals(Right(strString, strMatch.Length), strMatch);

    }

    public string MqStrMan_MakeStringStartWith(string strString, string strMatch)
    {
        if (MqStrMan_StringStartsWith(strString, strMatch) == false)
        {
            return strMatch + strString;
        }
        else
        {
            return strString; 
        }
    }

    public bool MqStrMan_StringStartsWith(string strString, string strMatch)
    {
       return String.Equals(Left(strString, strMatch.Length), strMatch);
    }

    public string Right(string value, int length)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        return value.Length <= length ? value : value.Substring(value.Length - length);
    }

    public string Left(string value, int maxLength)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return String.Empty; 
        }

        maxLength = Math.Abs(maxLength);
        return value.Length <= maxLength ? value : value.Substring(0, maxLength);
    }

    public string Format_Value(string strString)
    {
            return strString.Replace("'", "''");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Not seeing a `ProgId` attribute on the class, i.e. `ProgId("VNDBUtils.VNSqlFormatter")`. May or may not be the problem, I know I have one on all my COM Interop classes.

Comment: I didn't know if it was necessary or not, I will try it and get back to you. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also, is the `.tlib` file being generated?

Comment: Yes it is, I think the issue was with the ProgId because it seems to be working fine now! Thank you :) - I don't have enough rep to upvote, although I would If I could

Comment: No problem, I'll add it as an answer so we can get it out of the queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discussion in comments lead to the following, the `ProgId` attribute was not set.

```c#
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("3884D59D-AB76-41E7-82B6-21C66DBDCBF3")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("VNDBUtils.VNSqlFormatter")]
public class VNSqlFormatter : IVNSqlFormatter
{
    /* implementation information */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you edited the AssemblyInfo.cs file?

Typically, this is the default:

```
// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("e2e2a417-bd3d-414d-97f9-91196ce1c63a")]
```

You would need to set the `[assembly: ComVisible(false)]` to `true`.

Comment: Yes I have set that to true.

Answer (score 0):

Thought this was too long to add as a comment to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29834324/3195477).

The ProgID should be generated automatically. And it seems like it should have already been generated as the same string you added manually.

According to Microsoft documentation  [Assembly to Type Library Conversion Summary - Exported Type Conversion:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46f8ac6z(v=vs.71).aspx)

> The export process also automatically generates a programmatic
> identifier (ProgId) by combining the namespace and type name. For
> example, the ProgId generated for the managed LinkedList class shown
> in the previous examples is A.B.LinkedList.
>
> Combining the namespace
> and type name can result in an invalid ProgId. A ProgId is limited to
> 39 characters and can contain no punctuation characters other than
> periods. To avoid these limitations, you can specify a ProgId in your
> source code by applying the ProgIdAttribute, rather than allowing the
> export process to generate an identifier for you.

If you take out the ProgID attribute just as a test, you could then inspect the typelib which is created upon compilation (with a tool like OleView) and see what ProgID it is generating. Maybe there is a possibility it generates a ProgID which is invalid to VB6, though it doesn't seem like that would be the case from the code in your example.